# Firebase functions algolia onWrite

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I want the user I added for firebase to be automatically added to the algolia, and I created such a function, but I get some errors

My onWrite Functions

```
exports.updateIndex = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}').onWrite(event => {

        var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID,ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);
        const index = client.initIndex('Users');

        const userId = event.params.userId;
        const data = event.data.val()

        if (!data) {
          return index.deleteObject(bookId, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('User Removed from Algolia Index', userId)
          })}

        data['objectID'] = userId

        return index.saveObject(data, (err, content) => {
          if (err) throw err
          console.log('User Updated in Algolia Index', data.objectID)
        })
      });
```

[image: And my Database]

I am receiving such an error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
        at exports.updateIndex.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:43:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
        at next (native)
        at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
        at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
        at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
        at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Actually I don't understand database.ref('**/Users/{userId}'**)?
How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
exports.updateIndex = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}').onWrite(event => {
  const userId = event.params.userId;
  const data = event.data.val()
```

into this:

```
exports.updateIndex = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}').onWrite((change,context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const data = change.after.val();
```

The cloud functions were updated and `onWrite` now has two parameters `change` and `context`. To be able to retrieve the wildcards then you need to use the `context` parameter.

> The `context` parameter provides information about the function's execution. Identical across asynchronous functions types, context contains the fields `eventId`, `timestamp`, `eventType`, `resource`, and `params`.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database